# C# get/set value of html input field

Tags: c#, html, ext.net

Is it possible to get the value of the html input field (`expiration`) in C# after the user clicks outside of the field? And set the value from database to the html input field on page load or on refresh.
Here is my code:

```
<ext:Panel runat="server" Border="false">
     <Content>
            <label for="expiration"> Unknown date 2 </label>
            <input id="expiration" type="text" placeholder="DD(uu)/MM(uu)/YY(uu)" class="masked" title="title" runat="server" 
                                    pattern="^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|(uu\/([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\/[0-9]{1,4})|(uu\/uu\/[0-9]{1,4})|(uu\/uu\/uu)" 
                                    data-valid-example="01/05/18"> 
     </Content>
</ext:Panel>
```

Comment: As per @Alander 's answer, you need to add a `name` attribute to the input for it to get posted to the codebehind.

Comment: A better data-valid-example would be "31/05/18".

Answer (score 3):

It should normally be done with `Request.Form["elementName"]`.

In this case, `Request.Form["expiration"]` to access its value, change your input to use name instead of id   `<input name="expiration" ... />` for it to work

Comment: ok but I want to get the value after the user clicks out of the field. is that possible? and also get the value from db on page load and store it in the input field

Comment: is there a reason why you must use input? a textbox with autopostback can be easier.. a RegularExpressionValidator can be used with the textbox to validate the input as well